# if $f$ be continuous and one to one on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Claim :** let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a real valued function on $A$
>
> and  $D \subseteq{A}$ , function $f$ is continuous on $D$ , one-to-one.
>
> let $E=f(D)$ then : $f^{-1} :E \to D$ is continuous .

is it right ?Or should $D$ is compact. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** :
Consider : $$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x  & \text{if } x \in[0,1)\\
2-x & \text{if } x \in(2,3]
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous and one to one on $[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ but you can prove that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Comment: so .  so   $D$ should be an interval . is it right ?

Comment: Yes $D$ being an interval is enough

Answer (score 1):

No, $D$ doesn't have to be a compact set. Pick $$f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}, \quad f(x)=\frac 1x$$ which is continuous, one-to-one and it's also its own inverse.